# Add output or transfer data from child to parent project

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I use msbuild in main.proj to build a project like this:

```
 <MSBuild Projects="outs.proj" Targets="Build">
     <Output ItemName="CustomOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
</MSBuild>
```

Inside outs.proj I have a custom Target, I need to add an output from this target to get .dll,.pdb,..., and .mycustomfiles

How can I send data from child project to parent project ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you simply `Import` the dependant project, however the basic scenario you described can be achieved with `Target`'s `Outputs` or `Returns` and corresponding `Output`'s `TargetOutputs` although there are few caveats as it's designed for incremental builds and not as a data transfer object.

foo.build

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Foo1">
    <MSBuild Projects="bar.build">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="Bar" />
    </MSBuild>
    <Message Text="%(Bar.Identity)" />
  </Target>

  <Import Project="bar.build" />
  <Target Name="Foo2" DependsOnTargets="Bar">
    <Message Text="%(Bar.Identity)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

bar.build

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Bar" Outputs="@(Bar)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Bar Include="**\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I think I can't import bar.build project because it will update foo.build properties or items values resulting in a wrong behaviour. So, I try with TargetOutputs but I build using Targets="Rebuild", bar.build is generated: unable to get Bar outputs from Foo1.

Comment: @Alphapage write some sample failing code, bar.build doesn't have a Rebuild target hence my example is not relevant to your use case and nobody is a mind reader.

Comment: Just changed Rebuild;Bar in Targets and it works. I wasn't pointed to my Target. Thank you for telling me to check my target.