# How to pass a property value from one proj to another proj file that follows

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a MSBuild proj file like below:

In PreBuild.proj, I create a dynamic property with UsingTask:

```
<GetBuildNumber Condition="'$(BuildNumber)' == ''" MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0" StartYear="2012">
    <Output TaskParameter="BuildNumber" PropertyName="BuildNumber" />
</GetBuildNumber>
```

Now I want to pass this $(BuildNumber) to the PostBuild.proj.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how they are linked. Hopefully you have an overall orchestrating project that imports all you pre and post dependencies a la your standard Visual Studio-generated `.csproj` that imports all the neccesary `.targets` and `.props` and is the main entry point for MSBuild since you'd never call the `.targets` directly, they only make sense as part of a bigger build file. In case of such well-designed project file you just use a property, otherwise you can try [`Outputs` or `Returns`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25401413/384478) or worst case scenario [`WriteLinesToFile` & `ReadLinesFromFile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insanity).